# SQLCommand AddWithValue - What am I doing wrong?

Tags: asp.net, sqlcommand

```
protected void gridOmniZone_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            GridViewRow row = gridOmniZone.Rows[e.RowIndex];
            Int64 ID = Convert.ToInt64(gridOmniZone.DataKeys[e.RowIndex].Values[0]);
            string Description = (row.Cells[2].Controls[1] as TextBox).Text;
            string LatCenter = (row.Cells[3].Controls[1] as TextBox).Text;
            string LongCenter = (row.Cells[4].Controls[1] as TextBox).Text;
            string Radius = (row.Cells[5].Controls[1] as TextBox).Text;
            string Address = (row.Cells[6].Controls[1] as TextBox).Text;
            string City = (row.Cells[7].Controls[1] as TextBox).Text;
            string State = (row.Cells[8].Controls[1] as TextBox).Text;
            string PostalCode = (row.Cells[9].Controls[1] as TextBox).Text;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.usp_UpdateOmniZone"))
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.BigInt);
                cmd.Parameters[0].Value = ID;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", Description);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LatCenter", LatCenter);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LongCenter", LongCenter);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Radius", Radius);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Address", Address);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@City", City);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@State", State);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@PostalCode", PostalCode);
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();

            }
        }
        gridOmniZone.EditIndex = -1;
        this.BindGrid();
    }
```

My code above throws an error on `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery`.    The error is:

> stored procedure expects parameter @ID which was not supplied.

As you can see, I did provide the parameter.  Any idea what I am doing wrong?  The debugger is telling me that the variable `ID` is a valid integer value.

Comment: OT LatCenter, LongCenter and Radius sound like they should be numerical (float or double) instead of string. What are the actual types in the stored proc and target table? The types of the values should match the parameters

Answer (score 3):

I think the problem is that you forgot to set the CommandType to CommandType.StoredProcedure.

Answer (score 3):

I up-voted the other answer - the issue is that message is common if you don't set the command type to stored procedure.

And you ARE better off to strong type the values.

So, this:

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("dbo.usp_UpdateOmniZone",con))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.BigInt).Value = ID;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Description",SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Description;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LatCenter", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = LatCenter;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@LongCenter", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = LongCenter;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Radius", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Radius;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = Address;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@City", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = City;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@State", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = State;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@PostalCode", SqlDbType.NVarChar).Value = PostalCode;

        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

And you don't need the "close" connection - quite much the WHOLE point of the "using" block.